# How can I style Angular 10 Material Select (and others) in my own way

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to give my angular material dropdown menu its own style. I am using Angular 10. I have done a lot of research an tried a lot of things I could find on Stackoverflow and others, but when I copy approaches from the internet, the style of my mat-select doesn't change. Here my current code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';


interface Radius {
  value: number;
  viewValue: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing-page',
  animations: [],
  templateUrl: './landing-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing-page.component.scss'],

  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class LandingPageComponent implements OnInit { // The dropdown menu containing component
  // .....

  radiusList: Radius[] = [
    {value: -1, viewValue: "Nothing"},
    {value: 5, viewValue: "5km"},
    {value: 10, viewValue: "10km"},
    {value: 15, viewValue: "15km"},
    {value: 25, viewValue: "25km"},
    {value: 50, viewValue: "50km"},
    {value: 100, viewValue: "100km"},
  ]
  selectedRadius: Radius;
  
  
  // .....
}

// ---------------------------------
// app.module.ts

import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select'; 
// ...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LandingPageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSelectModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```css
.test.mat-select-panel {
    background: red; // also background-color does not work
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Umkreis</mat-label>
    <mat-select panelClass="test" [(ngModel)]="selectedRadius" name="radius">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let radius of radiusList" [value]="radius.value">
            {{radius.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Can somebody give me a hint how I can style the dropdown menu? Will that be everywhere the same way if I would use other components from Angular Material?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `::ng-deep` selector in your CSS.

For example:

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel {
    background: red; // also background-color does not work
}
```

But care, `::ng-deep`  force a style down through the child component tree into all the child component views and according to the official documentation, this way is deprecated.

You can find more information [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

Answer (score 1):

Just put your styles in the `styles.scss` file at the app level

Comment: Thank you this works, but I do not understand why. Do you have an explanation for this?

Comment: I think that these styles are applied globally after all the components have been compiled, so it overwrites the material styles